# How Do I set the HiDPI Scaling factor for the lock screen and log in screen?

Tags: release-loki, hidpi

I'm having problems setting the HiDPI scaling factor for the log in screen and lock screen. Thanks for your help!

elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki